# Is it possible to create a variable based on the value of more than one variable?

Tags: javascript

For example `A = 10`, i want to create a variable with the value in it.

Like this: `var i10` or if `A = 2`, i wanna create a variable like this `var i2`.

For e.g. `A = 10` and `B = 5`, i want a `var A10B5`, is that possible?

Edit: more information

Comment: Are you looking for arrays ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name

Comment: Have a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name

Comment: @GeraldSchneider you beat me by two seconds with the same reference

Comment: nonono what if i have more than one variables that i want in my varible?

For e.g. A = 10 and B = 5, i want a var A10B5, is that possible?

Comment: What is your ultimate requirement?

Comment: Are you looking at variable naming convention?

Comment: There is (almost) *never* a reason to create variables dynamically. What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: im doing a calendar and i need to create a variable for all the dates on the calendar. i figured that this would be a good way to do it.

Comment: Use a twodimensional array. `Dates[A][B] = 'value'`. It will save you a lot of redundant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, as explained in detail in [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name).

```
A = 10;
B = 5;

window['A' + A + 'B' + B] = 'Hello';

alert(A10B5);
// alerts: Hello
```

See a demo in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GeraldS/yEEva/).

I don't see the point of it though though, since you have to keep a reference of the name of this object it's easier to store the value in a local variable inside a function or object that has always the same name or use an array to store the value.

Proposed solution for the intended use:

Use a two-dimensional array:

```
Calendar[A][B] = 'value';
```

By creating dynamic variables you will have to rebuild the name of the variable every time you need to access it it. By using a two-dimensional array you can just use the array with both variables, that spares you the code to rebuild the variable name over and over again and makes it easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

```
var A = 10, B = 5;
window['A' + A + 'B' + B] = "You should avoid polluting global " + 
                            "scope at all costs.";
alert(A10B5);
```

Instead you should resort to objects:

```
var myVars = {}, A = 10, B = 5;
myVars['A' + A + 'B' + B] = "Just like this.";
alert(myVars.A10B5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create dynamic variables with eval() function

```
var a = 10;
eval("variable" + a + " = a");
```

this return a variable with name "variable10" and value "10".

Take a [look here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?571957-quot-dynamic-quot-i-variable-names-in-javascript) too!

For more information: [w3schools eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)

Hope it helps ^_^

Comment: Ouch. `eval()` should be used very very carefully and avoided if possible.

Comment: However, many people suggest it as a solution to create variable names dynamically..

Answer (score 0):

You can have `A = 10` and `B = A` which takes the same amount in a different variable, however, you also can make an if statement like

```
if(A > 10){ A = 11 }
```

Answer (score 0):

[check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name)

`a = 'varname';

str = a+' = '+'123';

eval(str);

alert(varname);
`

Comment: You provide a link to a good solution and accompany it with an example of a completely different, unrelated (and possibly dangerous) example?